# Python regexp scape characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to port an old program from C# to Python, and I need to use a regular expression that will match words, simply quoted words and double quoted words. I already have the regexp, which is shown below, but it's not matching anything when I try it in IDLE.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile("""[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'""")
>>> regex.findall("foo bar")
[('', ''), ('', '')]
```

I'm using a triple quoted string to enter the re, since it contains both simple and double quotes in addition to backslashes.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us examples of input and want you want to find in it

Comment: The example is the third line in the code. It should match any words, quoted or unquoted, separated by whitespace.

Comment: I just tried the redemo.py demo and it works, so I guess my code is not working only because of how the regexp string is entered. In the tkinter demo I just enter the unquoted regular expression as [^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` returns the contents of the capture groups. Since `foo` and `bar` are matched by `[^\s"']+`, all the capture groups are empty.

To get a list of match objects, use `re.finditer` instead:

```
>>> list(regex.finditer('foo bar'))
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 7), match='bar'>]
```